# problems with static 1d arrays in 2d arrays

Tags: java

I am trying to create static array which i initialize later in the method

Something like this

```
static Object[][] table;
static Object[] codeZero;
static Object[] codeOne;
```

I call this method from main

```
static void init(){
    table = new Object[][]{codeZero,codeOne};
}
```

and then in another method i try something like this

```
codeZero=new Object[2];
codeOne=new Object[2];
table[0][0]= new Integer(4);
```

when i try to print table[0][0] it gives me a null pointer exception

Comment: Can you include the code you're using to print it?

Comment: @DavidWallace the problem seems to be that OP instantiates the array using the default `null` values of `codeZero` and `codeOne` variables, then reassign these fields but the `table` (or `hashTable`) variable is still filled with `{ null, null }`.

Comment: sorry my fault.. i edited it

Comment: i am sry.. i edited the code there is no hash anywhere now

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - yes, I see all that.  But if he's just doing `System.out.println(table)`, there won't be a problem.  If he's iterating through the table, or trying to print an individual element of it, then he'll get into trouble.  I'm just trying to ascertain exactly what he's doing, so that I don't answer the question from a position of ignorance.  It's always difficult to solve people's problems when they only show you half the code.  And even more difficult when what they DO show is full of typos.

Comment: @DavidWallace you don't always need full code to understand OP. His question is very clear and note that OP even posted how the program behaves sequentially, so it wasn't hard to detect the error. Sadly, there are other cases when OP don't like to help him/herself nor the community to get his/her problem solved. Hopefully for us, this is not the case :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what's hapenning

1. Instantiating `table` variable with `null` elements:

   ```
   table = new Object[][] { codeZero, codeOne };
   ```
2. Change the references of `codeZero` and `codeOne` variables, the old references **will still** remain in `table`, they **won't** be replaced.

   ```
   codeZero = new Object[2];
   codeOne = new Object[2];
   ```
3. Since the old `null` references are still in `table`, you will get a `NullPointerException` when calling `table[0][<whatever>]`.

Possible fix: Initialize `codeZero` and `codeOne` before initializing `table`. Then, initialize `table` using your currently approach:

```
    codeZero = new Object[2];
    codeOne = new Object[2];
    table = new Object[][] { codeZero, codeOne }
```

Comment: so when i print codeZero[0] in my main method it should give me the object right since it is initialized?

Comment: so i should call the init function right after i initialize the codeZero[] right?

Comment: @sohil yes, you should. I would recommend to work on it and come back when you have a problem.